# "Trending" feature to predict number of views

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am working on a problem where I have access to a database with news articles, their publication date and the number of views they got 24hrs they got published.

**The objective is to be able to predict the number of views for any new article.**

I want to add a feature that, for a given article, gives an indication of the number of views / publications of all articles with a similar theme that happened a short time before the publication of this article. This would capture the "buzz" phenomenon. (If there has been a lot of articles on elections, then it is quite likely that a new article on elections will get lots of views.)

**Here is my strategy :**

We classify all articles among X themes.

We segment the timeline into Y timesteps.

For each timestep:

For each theme:

- we count the number of views of articles of this theme published in this timestep
- ditto for the number of publications
- we add these two values as features for all articles published in the next timestep

So, I was wondering if this violates the i.i.d. assumption? (Because, if I randomly separate the data into train/test, this injects information from the target values of the test set as a feature of the training set.) Is this "allowed"?

Am I missing something? Do you see another strategy?

Comment: A problem I can see is that, since each of your prediction will be based on features from the previous time interval, (let's say 1 hour ago), you make your `n+1` prediction dependent on the previous `n` prediction, and so you won't be able to predict "what will be the number of views for this article in 2 days?" - you'll need to predict time interval by time interval iteratively, adding error upon error.